# Incorrect result while adding with parseFloat in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

I want to perform addition of floating point numbers. I will always have always have only 2 decimal places.

However if I do:

```
         var num = 0;
         num += parseFloat("2434545.64").toFixed(2);
         num += parseFloat("454560.91").toFixed(2);
```

I get the value as `02434545.64454560.91`
It is appending instead of adding. Also will the addition be accurate always?

Answer (score 5):

`toFixed()` return a  String.
So you concatenate two `String`.
You should use `toFixed()` only in the last statement and you should not mix this invocation with a `+=` operator in a even statement because here :

```
num += parseFloat("2434545.64").toFixed(2);
```

`parseFloat("2434545.64").toFixed(2)` is evaluated first.
It produces a String.
Then its `num += String result` is evaluated.
So, it would concatenate a Float with a String. Which produces again a String concatenation and not an arithmetic operation.

Just invoke `toFixed()` in a distinct statement :

```
var num = 0;
num += parseFloat("2434545.64");
num += parseFloat("454560.91");
num = num.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution

```
var num = 0;
     num += 2434545.64;
     num += 454560.91;
console.log(parseFloat(num).toFixed(2));
```

Here is the documentation for parseFloat https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp